# KO input with edit mode and cancel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a knockout-backed text input, with the following properties:

- It's visible when focused (and a span with its value is visible
  otherwise)
- Escape key cancels the change
- Enter key submits the change
  (all of the above work)
- Losing focus on the input causes change submission

  - **UNLESS** the focus is lost when the user clicks on the cancel button

The **UNLESS** portion here is the only part I don't have working.  What's happening is when the input loses focus, the observable updates before the click on the "cancel" button calls the cancel function.

Here's my relevant code.

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="description-control">
        <!-- ko if:showDescEditBox -->
        <div class="description-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: description, 
                event: {keydown: handleKeypress, hasFocus: showDescEditBox}"></input>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button data-bind="click: onDescriptionSubmit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                <button data-bind="click: onDescriptionCancel"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:showDescEditBox -->
        <div class="description-display" data-bind="click: onDescriptionClick">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span data-bind="text: description"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

The view model:

```
    this.handleKeypress = function (data, event) {
        var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case Util.keyCodes.ENTER: 
                this.onDescriptionSubmit();
                return false;
            case Util.keyCodes.ESCAPE:
                _this.onDescriptionCancel();
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    };
    this.onDescriptionClick = function () {
        _this.showDescEditBox(true);
    };
    this.onDescriptionSubmit = function () {
        _this.showDescEditBox(false);
    };
    this.onDescriptionCancel = function () {
        _this.description(_this.dataObj().description);
        _this.showDescEditBox(false);
    };
```

The subscription to the showDescEditBox observable:

```
        this.showDescEditBox.subscribe(function () {
            if (!_this.showDescEditBox()) {
                if (_this.description() !== _this.dataObj().description) {
                    _this.update();
                }
            }
        });
```

Note `_this` is equivalent to `var self = this;`

Also, this is Typescript generated JS.  I chose to show the generated JS so as to limit the problem space to JS rather than discussing particularities of Typescript.  So if something looks a little odd with the `this` here and `_this` there please try to skip over it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible out of the box since it's all event based and the events fire independently.

You can do a couple of things:

- use a `setTimeout` in the `onblur` handler that waits for a couple of milliseconds so the cancel can clear the timeout before it actually fired. There are some issues with this like not knowing when the cancel will actually fire (the wait time might not be long enough). Also you'll have to somehow hook into the onblur event deep inside knockout
- Store the original value of the description in `onDescriptionClick` and restore the value of `description` to that backed up value in `onDescriptionCancel`. I think this will work fine since I think the events will get fired in the 'onblur', 'click' order.

Comment: I've seen UIs that do this (Jira for example). Is there some other means they're using to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem is that you're using knockoutjs. The framework will update the viewmodel as it sees fit and there is no way for you to hook into that. So as soon as the onblur is fired knockout does its thing. I updated the answer to include a second option.

Comment: Well I feel stupid - chalk it up to trying to over-engineer things I guess.  Of course a backup variable would fix the problem, and more reliably than any setTimeout scheme.  Thanks!

Comment: Well I take it back.  Turns out the cancel button in my form is  is disappearing before it receives the click, and I haven't been able to get a timeout to affect that fact.  I'm just going to turn off the 'disappear when click outside' functionality and just allow enter/esc and button clicks to submit the change unless another solution presents itself (including a non-knockout solution)